# Is that possible to get the file name in Paperclip validation message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, paperclip, paperclip-validation

I use Paperclip 2.3.11 in my Rails 3 application, and have the following validation:

```
validates_attachment_size :asset, :less_than => 2.megabytes, 
                          :message => "bigger than 2MB"
```

Is that possible to include the original file name in the message, so it will look like:

```
my_file.jpg bigger than 2MB
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you ought to be able to pass in a lambda for `:message`, e.g.:

```
validates_attachment_size :asset, :less_than => 2.megabytes, 
                          :message => lambda {|asset| "#{asset.file_name} bigger than 2MB" }
```

Comment: Doesn't work: `undefined local variable or method `asset_file_name' for #<Class:0x8de5bd8>`

Comment: Misha: Sorry about that. I've updated my code--give it another shot.

Comment: Sorry, Misha, but I'm out of ideas.